# Unable to print arraylist of different data types using java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a class:

**sample.java**

```
class sample

int val;
String str;
```

**constructor**

```
sample(String str,int val)

str=this.str;

val=this.val
```

**test.java**

```
ArrayList<sample> lst=new ArrayList<sample>();

lst.add(new sample("somedata",33)):

lst.add(new sample("somedata",33)):
```

send(lst) sending arraylist obj over a network.but i was wondering how i can print the values in the arraylist. I tried using iterator but it is only showing object references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override the `toString` method in your `sample` class. You could use:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return "str=" + str + " val=" + val;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution to this problem: implement the `toString` method on your `sample` class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return str + ", " + val;
}
```

Then you'll the field values of each instance.

Otherwise: access the fields from the loop:

```
for (sample s:lst) {
  System.out.println(s.str + ", " + s.val);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

override *toString()* method in your *class*

```
public String toString(){
return str+"," + value;
}

Iterator<Sample> itr = lst.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
system.out.println(itr.next().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use class names starting with an upper-case letter. Also your constructor is wrong, it should be

```
sample(String str,int val) {

this.str=str;

this.val=val

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement toString and you'll be fine if all you want is just printing objects.